# Merge columns based on condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, merge

I want to merge two columns, **lat.x** and **lat.y**, so I get a new column, **lat**.

Data:

```
lat.x    lat.y    lat
  1        1       1
  2        2       2
 NA        3       3
  4        NA      4
  5        6       5
```

I've tried:

```
df2$Lat <- ifelse(df$Lat.x == "NA", df$Lat.y, df$Lat.x)
```

Comment: `ifelse(is.na(df$lat.x), df$lat.y, df$lat.x)`: 1. Use `is.na()` to see if value is `NA`; 2. Colnames are `lat.x` not `Lat.x`

Comment: `R` is case sensitive, which means, that you should use the exact column names `lat.x`, `lat.y` and not the capitalized ones. 
Also for finding values which are `NA` you should use `is.na(df$lat.x)`.

Comment: The is.na works. The case-sensitive thing was just a typo. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test for NA with `x == "NA"` as this just test if `x` is a literal string with the characters `"NA"`. Instead you should use the base function `is.na()`.

This works:

```
df <- data.frame(
  lat.x = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5),
  lat.y = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5)
)

df$lat <- ifelse(is.na(df$lat.x), df$lat.y, df$lat.x)
```

Also, you should consider supplying the example data in a copy-paste'able format (like i have done above). This makes it easier to test your code and provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :)


And I'll keep that in mind for my next question. I'm very new to R, and also new to stackoverflow.